# What does "*y do in vim?

Tags: vim

I was reading through Gary Bernhardt's vimrc file and I saw that he maps <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>. After using help on various permutations of those characters I'm still unsure of what that's actually doing. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_04.html#04.7

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suitable for https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Vim was compiled with clipboard access, it is possible to access the <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> registers, which can modify the system clipboard. In this case, one can copy with e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> in visual mode, or <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>{motion}</kbd> in normal mode, and paste with e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Taken from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste)

More [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard)